# How do I get my form to save changes to labels?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in Microsoft Access 2010 with labels which are updated via VBA as certain processes and queries are run.

Two different buttons on the form initiate two separate VBA processes. After each process, a label is changed.

- **The first label** is changed to a date based on a file name after the first process (an import).
- **The second label** is changed to the date of the first label after changes from the import were applied.

I can then use

```
Me.Repaint
```

to ensure the form labels are updated. This works fine. I can see my labels change.

However, if I then close the form and reopen it (manually or programmatically), the changes to my labels are lost. I decided to try brute-forcing it:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "aForm", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm"
```

but this yields the same result--no changed labels.

Comment: If you want to make permanent changes to the labels, you must must do it with the form in Design View and then save the modified form design.

Comment: So I change to Design View from VBA?

Comment: `DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm", acDesign`

Comment: To provide such as functionality, you need to bind your form with table. So, during import process, you need to save the information which you want to display in the labels. Note, that source of label should always refer to the last imported data. That's all!

Comment: @HansUp That worked. Is there a way to do that without the application looking odd loading design view (just the property sheet popping up) and then going back to normal? I.e. a `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` equivalent for Access?

Comment: Check out the Access help topic for the *DoCmd.OpenForm Method*.  You can use *acHidden* for the *WindowMode* option, make your design changes while the form is not visible, save the modified form design, and later reopen that same form in Form View and visible.

Comment: Beautiful; thank you @HansUp! Should be an easy answer for you to write...

Comment: I'm busy with other stuff.  Please write it up yourself so I can upvote you.  :-)

Comment: @MaciejLos I'm not sure that applies. The label should always refer to the last file, but the date information isn't in the imported data itself. I don't believe there's any reason to bind the form to the table, since it doesn't edit/access any of the information directly.

Comment: Note that when you distribute your app as an ACCDE this will not work because you can't open forms in design mode when your front end is compiled. Table driving the labels is the way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for form changes to be saved, the form needs to be in **Design View**. You can change to **Design View** with VBA using the *View* parameter of `DoCmd.OpenForm`.

If you want to save all these changes and hide the form while it's in **Design View** from the user:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm", acDesign, , , , acHidden
DoCmd.Close acForm, "aForm", acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm "aForm"
```

The above and many more possibilities for opening forms can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx)!

(All the credit to @HansUp for the help!)

Comment: While this solution can work, design changes really should not be made during an application's runtime. Consider using textbox controls instead of labels where you can pass data like filenames and dates through VBA or macros. Textboxes can be formatted to look exactly like labels, so users will never know the difference!

Comment: @Parfait Tu es parfait; merci. Would that also work if I distributed it as an AACDE?

Comment: Yes it would. Textboxes are standard form controls.

Comment: @Parfait, is it possible for the textboxes to hold the last values when I reopen a form? That's what was nice about the labels.

Comment: Then bound textboxes to a table or do DLookUp/VBA recordset reference in form's OnOpen event.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: run the code that tweaks the labels as the form opens:

[Automatically execute some code after the UserForm is drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976680/automatically-execute-some-code-after-the-userform-is-drawn)

I used:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()' I placed at the top of the form's code area
    Set obj_controls = Me.Controls
    Call arrange_controls_in_UserForm(obj_controls)
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

The routine called from the sub above is not included. The OP seems to have code that accomplishes the desired changes to labels.

My additional code is in a Module in the Excel VBA project, though perhaps it could also be built within the form's code area.

My code is based on an example found here:
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/controls-collection.html

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

But I use a lines similar to:

```
   obj_controls("Label" & i).Left = xleft(i)
   obj_controls("Label" & i).Wide = wide(i)
```

The programmatic changes to the form's appearance are lost when the form closes, but they are active while the form is being used.

Programmatic changes to the form allow tweaking the design of the form without a lot of clicking and dragging with the mouse, etc.

DoCmd.OpenForm seems to be for Access. I couldn't get it to work in Excel's VBA.